# How to import all the contents from my Wordpress blog to my blog which I am currently building in this course?

Tags: python, django, wordpress, python-3.x, django-1.11

I mean to say is I have Wordpress webtsite for blogging and I am now planning to build a new custom blog from django and I want to import all the contents from the Wordpress to new django powered site as I have my own server and hosting Wordpress site from that personal server only with hostgator!!??  I sit possible to do that? As if I build new django powered site, and it will be basically new start again, I will loose all my audience for my previous post !! As I want all my post contents from the wordpress built blog transferred to my django powered blog.!! Please show me some way for this and in detail please!!

Comment: SO is for helping people fix their code, not for writing it. You should post your existing code with a description of how it isn't working.

Comment: @holdenweb ... i am learning to program in python and due to immediate needs i am initially  planning to launch my wordpress site and later as my website is done i ll be usiing that so i wanted to know if i can transfer all the content from wordpress to my new site?? if its possible then i will be proceeding with working on wordpress and if not i will concentrate on developing website with django framework!!

Answer (score 1):

It may help you
[django-wordpress](https://github.com/istrategylabs/django-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the luck with solutions like [django-wordpress](https://github.com/istrategylabs/django-wordpress), however it's apparently not under active support (last commit in 2014!), so you may need to move those data by hand.

For that, you would need to register this base in your settings and just run `inspectdb` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/legacy-databases/))

```
python manage.py inspectdb > wordpress_models.py
```

which should recreate your current structure. It could, by the chance, be enough to use those data, but you may need to process them somewhat (to remove, for example, some data generated by wordpress).